# Spring cannot connect to postgres when using docker

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to containerise a Spring Boot project that uses another containerised Postgres database, but it seems the Spring project cannot connect to the database because it cannot resolve the hostname.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN mvn clean install spring-boot:run -q
```

Docker compose:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    container_name: db
    expose:
      - "5432"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: nanobox
    networks:
      - app-network
  
  backend:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: nanobox
    volumes:
      - ./nanobox:/app
    environment:
      - SECRET=bigsecret
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - postgres


networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

application.properties:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
#debug=false

spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/nanobox
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.database=postgresql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.not_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
debug=true
spring.mvc.log-request-details=true
auth.secret={SECRET}
storage.prefix = /tmp/uploads/
```

**docker compose up** fails with the following exceptions:

```
#8 44.67 Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    [..]
#8 44.67 Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    [..]
#8 44.68 Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    [..]
#8 44.68 Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: postgres
```

It seems that for some reason docker compose refuses to start the postgres container before the Spring application, even the command:

```
docker compose up postgres backend
```

results in:

```
[+] Building 8.3s (8/8) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 31B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/maven:3.6.0-jdk-11                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1.5s
 => [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/maven:3.6.0-jdk-11@sha256:6a0430ded2cfaba7e16080f4cc097c9c65d1406b3b235d0fcfcfd84c354c4177                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 18.55kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [2/4] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [3/4] COPY . /app
```

Comment: Do you have a log from postgres container? Did it start properly?

Comment: that's actually a good question... it seems that it's not even started by the docker-compose command for some reason.

Comment: Can you remove -q from RUN command in your Dockerfile? It may be hiding an error.

Comment: I added it because it was flooding my logs and they would reach the limit, concealing the actual errors related to the impossibility of connecting to the database. : ```#8 44.19 [output clipped, log limit 1MiB reached]```

Comment: Try changing spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/nanobox to spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/nanobox. Your docker compose has postgres's container name as db where as in application.properties is not pointing to this container name

Comment: @mAsK: compose creates entries for both service and container name(s). The most obvious reason here for not having that name resolved is that the container/service is not started (crashed....)

Comment: @Zeitounator what would be the best way to force the spring container to wait for the postgres one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@david-maze 's solution was almost good for my case. However, I solved the problem with this following Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

# At build time, only compile the application but do not run it
RUN mvn clean package -DskipTests -q

# When you launch the container, this will be the main command
CMD mvn spring-boot:run
```

also had to add an alias for the database container:

```
postgres:
    image: postgres
    container_name: db
    expose:
      - "5432"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: nanobox
      networks:
        some-net:
          aliases:
            - auth-module.dev
```

Maven was running tests that resulted in container launch failure because there was no database.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to run `mvn spring-boot:run` from a Dockerfile `RUN` instruction; that happens while you're trying to build the image, not when you go to run the container later.  (It's similar to the difference between using `javac` to compile a source file and `java` to run the built class file.)  For reasons beyond the scope of this answer, the build phase can't connect to other containers, even if they're declared in the same `docker-compose.yml` file.

Split the Dockerfile into two separate lines to build the application, and then to run it as the main container command:

```sh
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .      # (don't repeat /app directory name)

# At build time, only compile the application but do not run it
RUN mvn clean install

# When you launch the container, this will be the main command
CMD mvn spring-boot:run
```

Comment: ```RUN mvn clean install -q``` results in the same error.. CMD is never reached. it seems that the postgres container does not start in the background for some reason.

Comment: Just compiling your application shouldn't require a database running, no?

Comment: I am honestly not getting your point, it might be the case that I'm still a beginner when it comes to theoretical knowledge about Spring and Docker. What I tried to say is that even with your changes, it does not work. Hostname is not resolved because postgres container is not up.

Comment: What is `mvn install` doing that it needs to connect to a database at all?

Comment: I do not know! The only thing that I know is that it fails, so my problem is not solved.

Answer (score 0):

First, inspect your Postgres container using the command `docker inspect pg`. pg is my Postgres container name. Check the network section. Ref the picture I have attached.  [docker_inpect_pg_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjAey.png). My Postgres docker container IP address is 172.17.0.2. And I replaced my old code with  `dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://172.17.0.2:5432/databasename");`

Comment: this problem was solved. Check accepted answer below (my own answer). Putting a hardcoded IP for the postgres docker container would be a bad idea, anway (and it was not the problem, the problem was that maven tried doing some DB related tests before the db was up).